# Allow single hyphen jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying following Code:

```
$('.alpha').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z-]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

How to allow only single hypen and also hypen will not be used in the beginning or end of string?

Comment: How would you be abel to test with hypen at the end as they type?

Comment: Are you using this code with <input> or <textarea> ?

Comment: @Tomas, is there any big difference for input or textarea? nope. And the question is on something else, on data processiong, so it's off-topic.

Comment: I am using input tag.

Comment: @Farside sorry for misleading question I just wanted to clarify that it's some kind of input element not div or something else.